# How to hide empty column in column hightcharts with multiple series

Tags: highcharts

I have multiple series to render in a column chart, but some of the column has a zero value and the chart left a space for the empty column. How can I hide/remove the empty column such as the Category 2 on 15 Jun in this example: [JSFILLDE](http://jsfiddle.net/G5S9L/7/)

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Testing'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Category I',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 14), 20],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 15), 30],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 16), 25],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 19), 10],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 20), 15]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Category II',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 14), 25],
            //[Date.UTC(2014, 5, 15), 10],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 16), 35],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 19), 25],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 20), 5]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Category III',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 14), 10],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 15), 20],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 16), 35],
            //[Date.UTC(2014, 5, 19), 25],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 20), 15]
        ]
    }]
});
```

Comment: The possible solution may be setting the `series.index` http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series.index. It will help exactly for your example: http://jsfiddle.net/SashkaCosmonaut/G5S9L/14/. 

But for the another cases where more zero values bars may appear, this solution will not help. As we can see here: http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/only-ever-3-columns-so-remove-gaps-inbetween-t27582/ _Unfortunately something like this is not supported. Even columns with nulls or zeros are taking space._ But I think more complex solution may exist.

Comment: @mortdale please share a workaround for this. I know the answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **stacking** and make some manipulations with **stack** in **series**, but the view of your chart will be changed.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked bar chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Testing'
            }
        },
        plotOptions : {
           column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
           }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Category I',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 14), 20],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 15), 30],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 16), 25],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 19), 10],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 20), 15]
            ],
            stack : 0
        }, {
            name: 'Category II',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 14), 25],
                //[Date.UTC(2014, 5, 15), 10],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 16), 35],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 19), 25],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 20), 5]
            ],
            stack : 0
        }, {
            name: 'Category III',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 14), 10],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 15), 20],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 16), 35],
                //[Date.UTC(2014, 5, 19), 25],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 20), 15]
            ],
            stack : 2
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: This is not a correct answer, but useful and easy to implement. Thanks.